# Modify 1 word in a line from File and the remain rest of the lines the same

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

This code change the modify data and it only remain the line which is modified not the rest of lines.

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
replacedLine = CurrentLine.replace(PASSWORD,password);
bw.write(replacedLine);

RESIDENTS_OLDDETAILS = new File(file);
RESIDENTS_OLDDETAILS.delete();

RESIDENTS_NEWDETAILS = new File(newfile);
RESIDENTS_NEWDETAILS.renameTo(file);

bw.close();
```

I want to change old line detail and remain the rest of the lines the same.

Example:

```
abc,1234,test 
ddd,2345,test1
```

to

```
abc,9999,test
ddd,2345,test1
```

Comment: when changing the line, how would you know about which word to be replace..???

Comment: i think it  easy to read the whole text, do the modification in memory and write back to the file

Comment: Hi, I'm using BufferedReader to read and separate the line into array. 9999 is array[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the updated lines in new variable and at the end write those new lines in new file.

```
StringBuilder updatedContents = new StringBuilder();
while(currentLine != null) {
    updatedContents.append(currentLine.replace(PASSWORD, password));
    updatedContents.append("\n");
    currentLine = reader.readLine();
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
writer.write(updatedContents.toString());
writer.close();
```

i think this will help you..